# Part of UV not being included in pack

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I have some trouble with a UV I created by combining two meshes.
So, I joined a head to a body. I then packed the UV's so they are better distributed. Than I baked a texture based on the new created UV.
I made a new material so I can texture paint to match them, but I noticed that the part where I used Loop Tools (bridge) to fill the gap between the two meshes, is not being affected by the paint. So I went back to select that part of the UV only to notice is doesn't appear in the unwrapped version.
Anyone knows what is happening here and what would be the solution? Maybe something I omitted in my workflow?
Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17nGDdcU2MKDADiLoSraEKX4DbTWOmERh/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you checked that the normals are correct in that part of the mesh? It sounds as if the faces there may be facing inwards instead of out. In Edit mode, select All and then SHIFT-N to recalculate the normals.

Comment: Thank you @John Eason! I just checked and recalculated but they seem to be facing the right direction.

Comment: have you unwrapped these new faces?

Comment: I think you'll need to share your blend file so that someone can have a look in that case. https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots , hmmm, that might be it. I haven’t thought it needs a new unwrap. Now, the thing is, how to unwrap just that part without having to mark all the seams again for the whole mesh( the UV was unwrapped by Human Generator for the body and by Face Builder for the head).

Comment: @JohnEason, yes, I’ll share it as well for a better reference.

Comment: just select that part and unwrap, then put the UV on a blank space of your image, and paint in the 3D view, for example with the Clone brush

Comment: Thank you @moonboots! Sound right!